# macro code to show much input range in dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro code to display more than one input range in dropodown list that I created in sheet2 via the form control.

I want an event with `IF` logic, where I have many names range from another sheet with the name eg: DaftarA (in sheet1 `C1:C30`), DaftarB (in sheet1 `C40:C60`), DaftarC (in sheet1 `C70:C90`).

How to write macros if the value in sheet2 C1 1, the dropdown list will display the input range of (name range) DaftarA, if the value is 2 then displayed in the dropdown list is (name range) dDftarB and so on ..

is there anything that can help? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can define a name for the list through the offset formula and use that name as a list for data validation drop down box.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!$F$1,0,Sheet1!$E$1,1)
```

where cell B1 is top of the list, cell F1 shows how much you offset down, cell E1 will control the length of the list. It will work however only if your multiple ranges are on the same sheet and in the same column

Answer (score 0):

It will also work if you define a name with the following formula

```
=IF(Sheet1!$F$1=1,test1,IF(Sheet1!$F$1=2,test2,IF(Sheet1!$F$1=3,test3)))
```

However in this case you need to name each particular range you want(like in this example test1, test2, test3) and of course you can't put too many nested formulas as it will get messy.